# efficient algorithm to find minimum of multivariable function

Tags: matlab, optimization, fminsearch

I have a multivariable function that I wish to minimize. The function has two input arguments, a vector c and a scalar \theta.

Using fmincon in MATLAB to solve the optimization problem for both c and \theta is complicated because certain values of \theta causes numerical errors. However, fixing theta, c can be easily obtained via fmincon without any errors.

So the plan now is to do a brute force approach, i.e. compute c for each value of \theta in the range 1:100 (although the true constraint for \theta is \theta \ge 0) and choose \theta (and the corresponding c) for which the objective value is minimized simply by plugging the estimated parameters back to the objective function.

Now this doesn't sound very efficient to me and I'm wondering if I can employ a bisection method-esque approach so that I would not have to go over all possible values of \theta in the range specified above.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to let fmincon do you work for you on both `c` and `theta`.  If it has problems getting a decent result when theta is included, it is likely because the elements in `c` and `theta` are of very different scales.  You should scale your equations so that all of the variables end up around a value of 1.0.  This *greatly* improves the performance (ie, speed) and accuracy of nearly any numerical optimization code.

So, if you suspect that the final values of `c` might end up being [1.0 0.001 10.0] and you suspect that theta might end up as [10.0], you would formulate your problem as

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> in your main program prior to invoking fmincon
c = [1.0 0.001 10.0]
theta = 10.0
foo_x = [c(:);thetha];
scale_fac = [1.0 1000.0 0.1 0.1];
x = foo_x .* scale_fac;  %scale your seed values to be near 1.0

>>>>>>>>>>>>>> inside your function
function err = myfunction(x,scale_fac)
foo_x = x ./ scale_fac;  %de-scale to get back to correct magnitude
c = foo_x(1:3);
theta = foo_x (4);

...rest of your code
```

Comment: Hi chipaudette, I see what you mean but I am afraid my objective function is more complicated than that. My objective function is the multivariate normal distribution and the \theta I am referring to is a correlation parameter. Thus, it appears in the determinant of the covariance as well as in the inverse covariance matrix. Depending on the initial value of theta, the objective function has to deal with almost singular matrices hence producing the errors...

Comment: You can do a fmincon within an fmincon.  So, at the top level, you'd have it search through theta (the variable that you were going to do brute force).  Inside that, where you are now given theta, you can have your function invoke fmincon again, this time solving for c.  Since fmincon will do something smarter than a brute force search, it might be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Bisection search over theta will only work if the objective function is convex (or quasiconvex) in theta. Otherwise, you risk finding a local min instead of a global min.

Doing a nested fmincon, as @chipaudette suggests, should work if you choose a solver capable of solving nonconvex optimization problems. (The [MATLAB help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html) on this topic is a little vague, but I think the SQP solver should be OK.) But I suspect it will be more efficient just to enumerate over the relevant range of theta, rather than using fmincon for it.